# FastCGI sent in stderr while reading response header from upstream

Tags: php, nginx, debian

I have recently installed Nginx(compiled) + PHP7-fpm + MariaDB on my VPS!
And i see on all my nginx/log files this error:

```
2017/11/17 17:45:15 [error] 23573#23573: *7 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: verify error, responseINVALID" while reading response header from upstream, client: 151.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "GET /wp-admin/index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-example.sock:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/wp-admin/index.php"
2017/11/17 17:45:18 [error] 23573#23573: *13 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: verify error, responseINVALID" while reading response header from upstream, client: 151.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-example.sock:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/wp-admin/index.php"
2017/11/17 17:46:18 [error] 23573#23573: *23 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: verify error, responseINVALID" while reading response header from upstream, client: 151.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-example.sock:", host: "www.example.com", referrer: "https://www.example.com/wp-admin/index.php"
```

My site, looks working fine, but i see this message on log files.
Does this error is important, or i have wrong made wrong my configuration files?
This my nginx config for virtual host file:

```
upstream backend-example {server unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-example.sock;}

server {
    listen              80;
    server_name         example.com www.example.com;
    root                /var/www/example/www;
    access_log          off;
    error_log           /var/log/nginx/example-error.log;
    index               index.php index.html;
    rewrite_log         on;
    if ($host != 'www.example.com' ) {
    rewrite         ^/(.*)$  http://www.example.com/$1  permanent;
    }
    location ~* ^/core/ {
    deny            all;
    }
    location / {
    try_files       $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }
    location /index.html {
    rewrite         / / permanent;
    }
    location ~ ^/(.*?)/index\.html$ {
    rewrite         ^/(.*?)/ // permanent;
    }
    location @rewrite {
    rewrite         ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
    }
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass    backend-example;
    }
    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|css|rss|atom|js|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
       access_log       off;
       log_not_found    off;
       expires          max;
       break;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location ~* wp-config.php {
        deny all;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
    deny            all;
    }


    ###
    # Pagespeed Settings
    ###
    location ~ '\.pagespeed\.([a-z]\.)?[a-z]{2}\.[^.]{10}\.[^.]+' { add_header '' ''; }
    location ~ '^/ngx_pagespeed_static/' { }
    location ~ '^/ngx_pagespeed_beacon' { }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    # Redirect non-https traffic to https
     if ($scheme != "https") {
         return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     } # managed by Certbot

}
```

P.S All my sites running well, only this errors apearing on log files!